# Is it faster to do WHERE IN or INNER JOIN in Redshift

Tags: sql, join, amazon-redshift

I have 2 tables in redshift:

table1

```
|   ids |
|------:|
|     1 |
|     2 |
|     6 |
|     9 |
|    12 |
```

table2

```
|   id |    value |
|-----:|---------:|
|    1 | 0.134435 |
|    2 | 0.767417 |
|    3 | 0.779567 |
|    4 | 0.726051 |
|    5 | 0.405138 |
|    6 | 0.775206 |
|    7 | 0.699945 |
|    8 | 0.499433 |
|   10 | 0.457386 |
|    9 | 0.227511 |
|   10 | 0.369292 |
|   11 | 0.653735 |
|   12 | 0.537251 |
|    2 | 0.953539 |
|   13 | 0.377625 |
|   14 | 0.973905 |
|    4 | 0.104643 |
|    1 | 0.450627 |
```

And I basically want to get the rows in table2 where **id** is in table1 and I have 2 possibilities:

```
SELECT *
FROM table2
WHERE id IN (SELECT ids FROM table1)
```

or

```
SELECT t2.id, t2.value
FROM table2 t2
INNER JOIN table1 t1
ON t2.id = t1.ids
```

I want to know if there is any performance difference between them.

(I know I could just test in this example to find out but I would like to know if there is one which is **always** faster)

Edit: `table1.ids` is a unique column

Comment: I ran into this problem. Spent 3 days troubleshooting. Turns out 'IN' and 'EXISTS' are not well optimized in RedShift by the looks. The "inner join" performs much faster. I'm working with TB sized Tables.  I'd go with inner join.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two queries do different things.

The `JOIN` can multiply the number of rows if `id` is duplicated in `table1`.

The `IN` will never duplicate rows.

If `id` can be duplicated, you should use the version that does what you want.  If `id` is guaranteed to be unique, then the two are functionally equivalent.

In my experience, `JOIN` is typically at least as fast a `IN`.  Of course, you can test on your data, but that is a starting point.

Comment: Great! Just edited the question to say that `table1.ids` is indeed unique. Thanks